# How to clone Control event handlers at run time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, event-handling

I want to duplicate a control like a Button, TextBox, etc.
But I don't know how I can copy event handler methods (like `Click`) to the new control.

I have the following code now:

```
var btn2 = new Button();  
btn2.Text = btn1.Text;
btn2.size = btn1.size;
// ...
btn2.Click ??? btn1.Click
```

Is there any other way to duplicate a control?

Comment: not sure why you would want to duplicate, but a simple copy past would create a new instance of the control.

Comment: Do you want to create a duplicate of let's say button at run time? with same event handler as previous button's?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To clone all events of any WinForms control:

```
var eventsField = typeof(Component).GetField("events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var eventHandlerList = eventsField.GetValue(button1);
eventsField.SetValue(button2, eventHandlerList);
```

Comment: Hrm, maybe. But is this documented somewhere? Is "events" guaranteed to be the name of that field for all eternity? Also, looks similar to the solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DelegateFromEvent.aspx).

Comment: @Cody - it works in .NET 2, 3.5 and 4. Will it work later - nobody knows. Is it a hack? Yes it is.

Comment: Just a word of caution to anyone who wants to do this. The events field in the Component class is an EventHandlerList. What you are doing here is copying the reference only (a pointer to its location in memory) such that both components now share the same list. Anytime you modify the event handlers list for any event in either Component (the one you copied from or the one you copied to), you are modifying the event handler list of both. Be aware of that and make sure that's what you want to do and it won't cause you any issues. I'd be careful calling this "cloning". It's more like "sharing".

Comment: I tried using this to automatically recreate a `ToolStripMenuItem`'s sub-items as `ContextMenu` sub-items to serve as right-click menu, but using this to copy the listeners from `ToolStripMenuItem` objects into the new `MenuItem` ones had no effect.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to [add the event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx) method for the new button control. C# uses the `+=` operator to do this. So you could simply write:

```
btn2.Click += btn1_Click
```

Alternatively, a somewhat more powerful approach is to [use reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx). Of particular use here would be the [`EventInfo.AddEventHandler` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler.aspx).

Comment: But I want duplicate control and I don't know "btn1_Click" function

Comment: @mrbm: As I mentioned in the comment to Vimvq1987's answer, if you don't know the name of the event handler method at run-time, you will need to use reflection. It's a bit more complicated, but much more powerful. The links I've provided have complete sample code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to duplicate the HTML element that will eventually render (including attached event handlers), you can use below extension method to output a copy of the HTML.

```
/// <summary>
/// Render Control to HTML as string
/// </summary>
public static string Render(this System.Web.UI.Control control)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.IO.StringWriter stWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stWriter);
    control.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then you can use it to out put a copy in the aspx markup like this:

```
<%= btn1.Render() %>
```

If you want to modify, say, the text on the copy, you could do a string Replace on the Rendered html, or you could set the Text on the original button, and reset it after the `Render` call in the asx, i.e.:

```
<% btn1.Text = "Text for original button"; %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand you question correctly. You can attach one event to multiple controls like this.

```
Button1.Click += button_click;
Button2.Click += button_click;
```

Comment: Yes I now, Assume I don't know the "button_click" function, I just have Button1 and I want get the functions linked to Click event.

Comment: Then I think you need to call the Button.PerformClick() method. It will execute the associated click event.

Comment: Yes it's good, but I can't use it directly,  btn2.Click += new EventHandler(btn1.PerformClick);  Error>> No overload for 'PerformClick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: I also can use this code, 
    btn2.Click += (ss,ee)=>{btn1.PerformClick();};

Answer (score -5):

the better approach is using a component class and inherit the control to that Class

```
public class DuplicateButton : OrginalButton
{

}
```

you can make changes in the partial class so there is no need for creating events

Comment: I don't think so. Event is attached to an instance of the button, not the class itself. Inheritance just does not work, in this case

Comment: I want to duplicate an control not a class!

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Event is attached to an instance, not to the class!