# How do I get a child window to send keys back down?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events

I am almost certainly missing something completely obvious. I have a singleton main form with various menu items with shortcuts. I have child windows which can be embedded on the main form or floating on their own. The main form class has a static member that points to the one extant main form, so the child windows can access its public functions. I want the hotkeys normally linked to the toolbar entries to work from the child windows, and I'd prefer not to duplicate the code. I know I have to invoke a keypress event on the main form, but I am running a complete blank today.

To give a simple example, there are menu items to save the current file and to center the window on the point the mouse is at, triggered by `Ctrl+S` and `Ctrl+E` respectively. They're set up as keyboard shortcuts in my Main Form, but the actual heavy lifting is done by my child window for the latter command. I have it temporarily fixed by catching a KeyDown event in my child window, but that means two different places that the same shortcut shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments to **Lukasz M** above, I needed to maintain the current menu structure for legacy reasons, namely that all of the engineers are accustomed to changing the Menu, and they want the menu shortcuts to automatically work. I could probably modify the central hotkey location using that custom message filter to generate Shortcut text for the Menu items, but that would add additional complexity that's likely to be undone the next time someone steps in to add a quick menu item. Thus, I went with the solution I alluded to in the comments with an invisible menu for the child windows.

Much to my surprise, if a menu has its `Visible` property set to false, the hotkeys work just fine. And the events associated with menu items in the main form work perfectly fine if invoked from a child form, as they're executed relative to the window where they are defined rather than by the window where they're invoked. Thus, my first solution was to fetch the `MenuStrip` from the main form and add it to the child form. That didn't work, as turning it invisible in the child form made it invisible in the main form as well. My next attempt involved creating a new hidden `MenuStrip` and adding the `ToolStripMenuItem` items from the main form's `MenuStrip` onto it. That broke the hotkey capability, possibly since the menu items now existed in more than one place. Finally, I created shallow copies of the menu items that contained only the shortcut key, the `Tag` property (necessary for a few menu items that made use of it), and the Event Handler (the last being done through the method described in [How to clone Control event handlers at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055038/how-to-clone-control-event-handlers-at-run-time)). After a bit of fiddling, I came to realize that I didn't need to maintain the structure of the menus and I only needed the items with shortcuts. This is what I wound up with:

**Main Form:**

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Returns copies of all menu shortcut items in the main form.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>A list containing copies of all of the menu items with a keyboard shortcut.</returns>
  public static List<ToolStripMenuItem> GetMenuShortcutClones()
  {
     List<ToolStripMenuItem> shortcutItems = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>();

     Stack<ToolStripMenuItem> itemsToBeParsed = new Stack<ToolStripMenuItem>();

     foreach (ToolStripItem menuItem in mainForm.menuStrip.Items)
     {
        if (menuItem is ToolStripMenuItem)
        {
           itemsToBeParsed.Push((ToolStripMenuItem)menuItem);
        }
     }

     while (itemsToBeParsed.Count > 0)
     {
        ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = itemsToBeParsed.Pop();

        foreach (ToolStripItem childItem in menuItem.DropDownItems)
        {
           if (childItem is ToolStripMenuItem)
           {
              itemsToBeParsed.Push((ToolStripMenuItem)childItem);
           }
        }

        if (menuItem.ShortcutKeys != Keys.None)
        {
           shortcutItems.Add(CloneMenuItem(menuItem));
        }
     }

     return shortcutItems;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Returns an effective shortcut clone of a ToolStripMenuItem. It does not copy the name
  /// or text, but it does copy the shortcut and the events associated with the menu item.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="menuItem">The MenuItem to be cloned</param>
  /// <returns>The newly generated clone.</returns>
  private static ToolStripMenuItem CloneMenuItem(ToolStripMenuItem menuItem)
  {
     ToolStripMenuItem copy = new ToolStripMenuItem();
     copy.ShortcutKeys = menuItem.ShortcutKeys;
     copy.Tag = menuItem.Tag;

     var eventsField = typeof(Component).GetField("events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
     var eventHandlerList = eventsField.GetValue(menuItem);
     eventsField.SetValue(copy, eventHandlerList);

     return copy;
  }
```

**Child Form:**

```
  private void OnRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // Refresh the hiddenShortcutMenu.
     List<ToolStripMenuItem> shortcutList = MainForm.GetMenuShortcutClones();
     hiddenShortcutMenu.Items.Clear();
     hiddenShortcutMenu.Items.AddRange(shortcutList.ToArray());
  }
```

Inside the child form's constructor, I instantiated the `hiddenShortcutMenu`, set `Visible` to false,  assigned it to my child form's control, and set the event. The last was a bit fiddly in that I had to have it periodically refresh since the menus sometimes changed according to context. Currently, I have it set to the `Paint` event for maximum paranoia, but I think I'm going to try to find a way for the main form to signal that it's changed the menu structure.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be few solutions to handle key shortcuts. 
One of them could be installing keyboard hooks as suggested [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx). 
You can also try to handle this by adding custom message filter, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078366/c-sharp-system-windows-forms-keys-how-to-keep-application-hotkeys-in-one-pla), however, I haven't verified the code posted there.

The solution with hooks seems to be a little tricky, so You may want to try custom message filter first.

Comment: I'm also exploring another possible solution. Since all of these hotkeys are menu items, it looks like I can add that menu to the other window and then set `Visible` to false. That means you can't navigate through the menu, but all of the hotkeys remain enabled.

Comment: You could define shortcuts handling in a public methods of a separated class and call those methods from both main and child windows. You can catch all key down events as you are doing now and process them inside this class to put all shortcuts handling in one place.

Comment: {nods} Part of the issue is that things have always been done as Menu items. Thus, they already have the short-cuts set up that way, and developers expect it to work that way. Copying the menu items seems to be working nicely so far, testing for corner cases.