# How to clone value changed event from control at run time

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls, clone

I tried to clone the events from one NumericUpDown to another on. I found a solution that fits nearly all my needs her:

[How to clone Control event handlers at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055038/how-to-clone-control-event-handlers-at-run-time)

Surprisingly, the ValueChanged - Event will not be cloned and I have no clue why.

Heres my code

```
        NumericUpDown numericUpDown2 = new NumericUpDown();

        FieldInfo eventsField = typeof(Component).GetField("events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var eventHandlerList = eventsField.GetValue(numericUpDown1);
        eventsField.SetValue(numericUpDown2, eventHandlerList);

        numericUpDown2.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        numericUpDown2.Name = "numericUpDown2";

        Controls.Add(numericUpDown2);
```

numericUpDown1 contains Events for ValueChanged, KeyDown, Validating, Validated, Enter, Leave and Click. For example:

```
private void numericUpDown1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Validating " + ((Control)sender).Name);
    }
```

I write some debug infos to the output Window which shows following for numericUpDown1:

- Validating numericUpDown2
- Validated numericUpDown2
- Enter numericUpDown1
- Value changed numericUpDown1
- Click numericUpDown1

And for numericUpDown2:

- Validating numericUpDown1
- Validated numericUpDown1
- Enter numericUpDown2
- Click numericUpDown2

Just the same without the value changed event. To make it work I have to add

```
numericUpDown2.ValueChanged += numericUpDown1_ValueChanged;
```

But this isn't the solution I'm searching for. I dont understand why the ValueChanged - Event is something special and not copied to. (I know that i only get a reference to the events and when I add/remove an event from one control the other is also affected, but this is exactly what i want)

btw... is numericUpDown the only control with ValueChanged - Event?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do you want to clone *events*? Why don't you attach event handlers manually? It's cleaner and doesn't need any hack.

Comment: `ValueChanged` event of `NumericUpDown` uses a different pattern that common events. It stores in `onValueChanged` rather than an `EventHandlerList`. To see the common pattern of events for controls, take a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-handle-multiple-events-using-event-properties?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ValueChanged`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NumericUpDown.cs,7d1c630de9442fd4) event of `NumericUpDown` uses a different pattern that common events. It stores in `onValueChanged` rather than an `EventHandlerList`:

```
private EventHandler onValueChanged = null;
public event EventHandler ValueChanged {
    add {
        onValueChanged += value;
    }
    remove {
        onValueChanged -= value;
    }
}
```

It basically means, copying the event `EventHandlerList` will not do the tick for you here.

To see how to use event properties in controls, take a look at this document:

- [How to: Handle Multiple Events Using Event Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-handle-multiple-events-using-event-properties?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explains why it doesn't is in the list. And unfortunately the Event Handler in only private, so I have no chance to get it out. So I have to do it in some other way but thats ok.

Comment: No problem. I'd advise against copying events. Instead, add them all manually.